# Which cygwin package contains ip command?

Tags: cygwin

I need the `ip` command in cygwin. I discovered that it's part of the `iproutes2` package. But cygwin doesn't have that package??

I what cygwin package can I find `ip` command?

(I need to find the gateway, and I don't want to use Windows' `ipconfig` command as my script needs to be portable)

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/721954/how-do-i-get-linux-commands-and-scripts-to-work-on-cygwin

Comment: @Kusalananda that detals the basics, I know my way around cygwin, just cant find that command, maybe its in a different package bu the package search reveals nothing :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ip` command is not available in any official Cygwin package (at the time of writing).

You may search the contents of all Cygwin packages using the ["Cygwin Package Search" page](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi), which allows you to search using regular expressions.

The `ip` command *is* however available in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (look for "Ubuntu" in the "Microsoft Store" app on Windows 10), but I can't say anything about whether it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why such basic tools are not part of cygwin? Also `ifconfig` is not available. Thats weird

Comment: @lonix Cygwin provides some of the user-level tools that you would often find in Linux, but since it does not provide a Linux kernel, it can hardly be said to be "a Linux". `ifconfig` and `ip` are administrative tools that are usually available on Linux systems, but they are in no way standard tools on all Unix systems (`ifconfig` usually exists, in one form or another, but there's no guarantee). The Cygwin maintainers have opted to not try to provide admin tools for the underlying Windows OS.